# Shell Script to read text File line by line and append to variable with a word in between

Tags: shell

I have a text file like this:

```
abc:value
test:value
```

I want to read these line by line and append to a variable in my shell script and also add a custom string.
So I want a variable that has: "*Hello abc:value Hello test:value*"

I used :

```
for line in $(cat $hdr_file)
do
    HDRS="-H $line"
    echo $HDRS  
    hdrtxt=$HDRS            
done
echo $hdrtxt
```

But `$hdrtxt` printed only has last line but does not retain other lines read from the file.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't read lines of file with `for` loop in shell/bash (it'll split on any whitespace (space, tab, newline) by default).
In your simple case it's enough to use `printf` + `sed`:

```
hdrtxt=$(printf "%s " $(sed 's/^/Hello /' "$hdr_file"))
echo "$hdrtxt" 
Hello abc:value Hello test:value
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$hdrtext` is being overwritten with each run of the loop.  To append to a shell variable, include the variable itself in each assignment:

```
unset hdrtxt
while read line
do
     HDRS="-H $line"
     echo $HDRS
     hdrtxt="$hdrtxt$HDRS"
done < $hdr_file
echo $hdrtxt
```

Output:

```
-H abc:value
-H test:value
-H test:value-H abc:value
```

---

Note:  the `$HDRS` variable isn't necessary, and the in-loop `echo` seems merely diagnostic, so the code can be simplified:

```
unset hdrtxt
while read line
do
     hdrtxt="${hdrtxt}-H $line"
done < $hdr_file
echo $hdrtxt
```